# A convex set is homeomorphic to cone of its boundary

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry

The statement in the title of the question is used in the proof of [Theorem 2.1 in the page for balls on nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ball). I am not sure if we also need the set to be compact.

> **Theorem 2.1** A compact convex subset $D$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ with nonempty interior is homeomorphic to $D^n$.
>
> ***Proof***. Without loss of generality we may suppose the origin is an  interior point of $D$. We claim that the map $\phi:v\mapsto v/\lVert v \rVert$ maps the boundary
> $\partial D$ homeomorphically onto $S^{n-1}$. By convexity, $D$ is homeomorphic to the cone on $\partial D$, and therefore to the cone on $S^{n-1}$ which is $D^n$.

> The claim reduces to the following three steps.
>
> 1. The restricted map $\phi:\partial D\to S^{n-1}$ is continuous.
> 2. It's surjective: $D$ contains a ball $B=B_{\epsilon}(0)$ in its interior, and for each $x\in B$, the positive ray through $x$ intersects $D$ in a bounded half-open line segment. For the extreme point $v$ on this line segment,
>    $\phi(v)=\phi(x)$. Thus every unit vector $u\in S^{n-1}$ is of the form
>    $\phi(v)$ for some extreme point $v\in D$, and such extreme points lie in $\partial D$.
> 3. It's injective: for this we need to show that if $v,w\in\partial D$ are distinct
>    points, then neither is a positive multiple of the other. Supposing otherwise,
>    we have $w=tv$ for $t>1$, say. Let $B$ be a ball inside $D$ containing $0$; then
>    the convex hull of $\{w\}\cup B$ is contained in $D$ and contains $v$ as an interior point, contradiction.
>
> So the unit vector map, being a continuous bijection $\partial D\to S^{n-1}$
> between compact Hausdorff spaces, is a homeomorphism.  ▮

I know the construction of a cone. If $X$ is a topological space, cone on $X$ is  $(X \times I) / (X \times \{0\})$ where I is the unit interval and $/$ is taking quotient, "cylinder $X \times I$ collapsed at one end".

Can someone help me prove the statement with simpler concepts such as compactness, connectedness, closedness, convexity but not contractibility?

Comment: Can you type out the cited "Thm 2.1"?  Posts here are supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited.

Comment: Your edit isn't what's intended.  It removed the source of your question.

Comment: You need compactness: for example the claim is clearly false for all of $\Bbb{R}^n$, which is convex.

Comment: Where does contractibility even get used?

Comment: I suppose in the proof of what I am asking one can use contractibility but I am not sure how.